# What's the best way to represent a time period in Java?

Tags: java, date

What's the best way to represent a time period in Java? May I use 2 Date objects or is there a better way?

I.e. all April, the hole 3rd week of July, from January to March, etc.

Comment: What do u mean represent? like 2011-04-01 TO 2011-07-09?

Comment: @RMT that's exactly what I meant

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the usual link to Joda when in comes to time + Java:

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/Period.html

Edit: The relevant link for this specific question is http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/Interval.html

Comment: Thanks Waldheinz, I think I didn't explain myself correctly, I took a look at Joda (didn't know about it) and I found the Interval class, that represents what I need.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit lazy when digging out the link. Updated with this.

Comment: @Waldheinz, I know Joda is great and everything, but doesn't this recommendation seem a little "over the top"? what's wrong with using the standard Java library?

Comment: @mre There's nothing really wrong with the standard Java classes, but I think it always had a bad API (and lots of it's methods are deprecated today). So my *recommendation* goes with Joda, and when your applications grows you'll be happy you started with it. But it's really a matte of taste.

Comment: @Waldheinz, I prefer to not use third-party libraries unless I absolutely have to. :)

Comment: @mre I did it just like you until I started using Maven. :-)

Comment: @mre I know it feels heavy-handed, but actually it's not over-the-top at all. The correct way to solve a standard problem is to use battle-hardened library code rather than your own untested code. And, Joda-Time is effectively going to be included in the JDK soon, there was a proposal to do it for Java 7 but they didn't manage, perhaps Java 8?

Answer (score 13):

I see the answers are quite old.

As of `Java 8`, we can use the native `Java.Time` which is partially based on `Joda Time` and makes the manipulations on dates very easy.

Take a look at `Period`, `Duration` and `LocalDate` on

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html
- https://dzone.com/articles/deeper-look-java-8-date-and

Comment: well but an `Interval`of Joda Time is much more expressive than using the new Java 8 objects... there is nothing comparable to it. You have to use 2 temporal objects (as we did in the past) or a starting date and a period... no way

Answer (score 4):

[Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) solves all your date/time troubles. It has a data range type.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid using Joda for some reason, then writing a class that wraps a pair of dates (or the underlying Long values) would be OK, but you'll need to write any methods you need for comparing ranges or determining if a date falls within a range, etc.

Comment: Do you have an idea how to convert long value to more usable information, like number of days between two dates, etc ?

Comment: I'd suggest reading the JodaTime sourcecode! Depending on your definition, number of days is timezone-dependent, so is not at all trivial to calculate.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use 2 different dates, use 2 different dates and use SimpleDateFormat. Its very simple to use.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
format.parse(new Date());
```